# Sacrificing a creature - Magic the gathering

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My question came up after I had a disagreement over what it means when a card states “sacrifice a creature” as it’s ability. The disagreement is in whether or not this text allows a player to sacrifice ANOTHER players creature. The rules for sacrifice didn’t clear up the issue for me, the ruling is still vague enough that I could conceivably sacrifice my opponents creature in a game and think it’s perfectly legitimate. Anyway I wanted to get some feedback on this.

Comment: Can you let us know what rules / ruling you were reading that is vague?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can only sacrifice a creature you control.**

A few sources...

From the [quick start guide](http://media.wizards.com/2014/docs/EN_M15_QckStrtBklt_LR_Crop.pdf):

> **sacrifice**
>
> > Sometimes a card tells you to
> >     sacrifice a creature or some other permanent.
> >     To sacrifice a permanent, you move it from
> >     the battlefield to your graveyard. You can’t
> >     regenerate it or save it in any way. **You can
> >     sacrifice only your own permanents.**

From the glossary in the [basic rules](https://www.wizards.com/magic/rules/en_mtgm11_rulebook_lr_web.pdf), page 31:

> **Sacrifice**
>
> > To choose one of your permanents on the battlefield
> >     and put it into its owner’s graveyard. **You can sacrifice
> >     only permanents you control.** Sacrificing a permanent
> >     is different from destroying it, so the permanent can’t be
> >     regenerated. You can sacrifice a permanent only if a spell
> >     or ability tells you to, or if it’s part of a cost.

And the comprehensive rule where that comes from:

> 701.15a To sacrifice a permanent, its controller moves it from the battlefield directly to its owner’s graveyard. **A player can’t sacrifice something that isn’t a permanent, or something that’s a permanent he or she doesn’t control.** Sacrificing a permanent doesn’t destroy it, so regeneration or other effects that replace destruction can’t affect this action.

Comment: Ah I did not see that specific wording, thank you that’s what I was looking for! I think the wording I had seen was something along the lines of “player removes target permanent from the battlefield”. But this clears it up once and for all. I guess this means you have to use abilities other than sacrifice to get rid of an opponents creatures.

Comment: @Cameron Belt, Any definition of sacrifice that uses the word "target" is wrong.